# Convert a Part to File and Read Excel File

Tags: java, excel, servlets

I am uploading an excel file to a servlet and trying to read its content. I am able to upload and send the file to the servlet. Over at the servlet, I am able to get the upload as a Part and read its name, file size and content type correctly. But how do I use this 'Part' to read as a file?

I am trying to use POI to read the Excel file. It requires me to pass in a file thus I passed in the 'Part' and cast it as a File. At runtime it returns an exception telling me that casting is not allowed.

I don't see a request.getFile option. Is there anyway to come around to make that Part into a File? Or another way to request File instead of Part. Please advice.

```
 <!-- HTML -->
    <form method="post" action="MyServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>

    //Servlet
public class ExcelUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                          HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Part filePart = request.getPart("file");

        if (filePart != null) {
            // These prints out the correct data
            System.out.println(filePart.getName());
            System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
            System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());
        }


        //Need to read excel file as follows  but how do I call the filepart here? 
        FileInputStream fis  = new FileInputStream((File)filePart);//cast doesn't work
        HSSFWorkbook wb  = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        for(Row row : sheet){
            for (Cell cell : row){
                System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use getInputStream:

```
HSSFWorkbook wb  = new HSSFWorkbook(filePart.getInputStream());
```

Not tried but this method is in the interface of Part.

Comment: Doesn't work. Compiler error says cannot resolve constructor.

Comment: Do you mean, the constructor of HSSFWorkbook indeed needs a FileInputStream instead of a simple InputStream? In this case you have to copy the received InputStream into a file, and open it again. But I doubt: From the java doc:

Comment: HSSFWorkbook(java.io.InputStream s)
Companion to HSSFWorkbook(POIFSFileSystem), this constructs the POI filesystem around your InputStream, including all nodes.

Answer (score -1):

** Jars required for this are:
    cos-multipart.jar,
    jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar,
    jackson-core-2.2.3.jar,
    jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar,
    poi-3.9.jar,
    where **fileUploader** is the name of the fileupload control in view.**

```
`protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


            MultipartRequest multi = new MultipartRequest(request, ".",1024 * 1024 * 50);

            String fileName = multi.getFilesystemName("fileUploader");
            String fileContent = multi.getContentType("fileUploader");
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(fileName);


               // l_obj_Out.print("Test2---->");
                //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
                HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

                //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
                HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                //Iterate through each rows one by one
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                String TenaID = "";         //where TenaID  is column name in excel
                String BuDoSeq = "";
                String BuDoDesc = "";
                String BuDoActive = "";

                List<Map<String, String>> output = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
                {
                    Row row = rowIterator.next();
                    if(row.getRowNum() == 0){
                        continue;
                    }
                    //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                    Map<String, String> buyerValueMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
                    TenaID = "";
                    BuDoSeq = "";
                    BuDoDesc = "";
                    BuDoActive = "";

                    Cell cell = null;
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                    {

                        cell = cellIterator.next();
                        TenaID = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        cell = cellIterator.next();
                        BuDoSeq = ""+cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        cell = cellIterator.next();
                        BuDoDesc = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        cell = cellIterator.next();
                        BuDoActive = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        //cell = cellIterator.next();


                        buyerValueMap.put("TenaID", TenaID );
                        buyerValueMap.put("BuDoSeq", BuDoSeq );
                        buyerValueMap.put("BuDoDesc",BuDoDesc);
                        buyerValueMap.put("BuDoActive", BuDoActive );




                    }
                    output.add(buyerValueMap);

    //              l_obj_Out.println("");
                }
                file.close();
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                  response.setContentType("application/json");
                  mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), output);

    }`
```

**the response will contain the json format of the file uploaded.**